# jqgrid loading json datas from server into treegrid doesn't display datas

Tags: json, jqgrid, treegrid

I'm newbie with jqGrid and I have build a jqGrid treeGrid with local datas and all is fine.
But now I'm trying to do same thing with remote JSON datas and I can't obtain treeGrid display my datas.
Here is treeGrid conf :

```
$("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({ 
    url:"sg511e.php?id="+row_id+"&btr="+btr, 
    datatype:"json",
    mType:'POST',
    loadui: "disable",
    colNames:['id','Prestations'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id',width:100,hidden:true},
        {name:'name',index:'name',width:785,sortable:false}
    ],
    pager: pager_id, 
    sortname: 'id', 
    sortorder: "asc", 
    hiddengrid:true,
    gridview: true,
    treeGrid:true,
    treeGridModel: "adjacency",
    treedatatype: 'json',
    ExpandColumn: 'name',
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: "rows"
    },
```

and JSON datas :

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "total": 1,
    "records": 1,
    "rows": [
        {
            "cell": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "ECHANGEUR",
                "level": "0",
                "parent": "",
                "isLeaf": true,
                "expanded": false,
                "loaded": true
            }
        },
        {
            "cell": {
                "id": "1_1",
                "name": "Intervention Aller sur Site",
                "level": "1",
                "parent": "1",
                "isLeaf": true,
                "expanded": false,
                "loaded": true
            }
        },
        {
            "cell": {
                "id": "1_1_1",
                "name": "Date et heure d'arrivée sur le site",
                "level": "2",
                "parent": "1_1",
                "isLeaf": false,
                "expanded": true,
                "loaded": true
            }
        },
        {
            "cell": {
                "id": "1_1_2",
                "name": "Consignation de l'échangeur",
                "level": "2",
                "parent": "1_1",
                "isLeaf": false,
                "expanded": true,
                "loaded": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't see what I'm wrong so I hope you can bring some help and explain my error.
Many thanks in advance
JiheL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should fix the JSON data:

- replace `"parent": ""` to `"parent": "null"` in the root element
- you should invert the values of `isLeaf` property: change all `true` values to `false` and change all `false` values to `true`
- you should remove `"cell"` part from all items
- The value `"records": 1` don't corresponds 4 items of data. I suppose that the correct value should be `"records": 4`, but the best will be to remove the `pager` from the list of options of the grid. In the case setting of any `page`, `total` or `records` will be not important.

You can more simplify the data and remove the `rows` part from JSON data. In the case we have to change the `root` property of `jsonReader` to `root: function (obj) { return obj; }`. As the result you can use the following simple JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "ECHANGEUR",
        "level": "0",
        "parent": "null",
        "isLeaf": false,
        "expanded": false,
        "loaded": true
    },
    {
        "id": "1_1",
        "name": "Intervention Aller sur Site",
        "level": "1",
        "parent": "1",
        "isLeaf": false,
        "expanded": false,
        "loaded": true
    },
    {
        "id": "1_1_1",
        "name": "Date et heure d'arrivée sur le site",
        "level": "2",
        "parent": "1_1",
        "isLeaf": true,
        "expanded": true,
        "loaded": true
    },
    {
        "id": "1_1_2",
        "name": "Consignation de l'échangeur",
        "level": "2",
        "parent": "1_1",
        "isLeaf": true,
        "expanded": true,
        "loaded": true
    }
]
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user2132268.htm) demonstrate the results of the changes. After extending the grid looks like on the picture below

[image]

The code which I used in the demo is:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: "user2132268.json",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: [ 'id', 'Prestations'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'id', width: 100, key: true, hidden: true},
        {name: 'name', width: 785, sortable: false}
    ],
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: "asc",
    hiddengrid: true,
    gridview: true,
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: "adjacency",
    ExpandColumn: 'name',
    ExpandColClick: true,
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: function (obj) { return obj; } },
    height: "auto"
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for your kind help, that rocks fine ! Far to become expert with jqGrid but I'm working on this ! JiheL