# JqGrid formatter integer undefined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

I have being trying to populate list of data in a grid for this purpose I have used [JqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). I have installed jqGrid plugin from nuget manager and from [online tutorial](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx/) I have been trying to implement the same.

This is what I have done so far:-

> View:-

```
<h2>Search</h2>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">        
        <table id="tblRecruiterGrid"></table>
        <div id="dvPagination"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/recruiter.js"></script>
```

> Controller:-

```
public ActionResult RecruiterGridData(string sidx = "", string sord = "", int page = 1, int rows = 10)
{
    var vData = recruiterRepo.GetAllByRelation();
    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;
    int totalRecords = vData.Count();
    int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
    switch (sidx)
    {
        case "RID":
            vData = sord == "desc"
                    ? vData.OrderByDescending(x => x.RecruiterID).ToList()
                    : vData.OrderBy(x => x.RecruiterID).ToList();
                    break;
        default:
            vData = sord == "desc"
                    ? vData.OrderByDescending(x => x.RecruiterID).ToList()
                    : vData.OrderBy(x => x.RecruiterID).ToList();
                    break;
    }
    var vResult = vData.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = totalPages,
        page = page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = vResult.Select(x => new
        {
            RID = x.RecruiterID,
            RecruiterName = x.RecruiterName,
            Email = x.Email,
            CompanyName = x.CompanyName,
            Designation = x.Designation,
            Mobile = x.Mobile
        }).ToList()
    };
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

> Javascript:-

```
$(function () {
    $('#tblRecruiterGrid').jqGrid({
        url: "/Recruiter/RecruiterGridData/",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'get',
        colNames: ['RID', 'Recruiter Name', 'Email', 'Company Name', 'Designation', 'Mobile'],
        colModel: [{ key: true, hidden: true, name: 'RID' },
                    { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'RecruiterName' },
                    { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'Email' },
                    { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'CompanyName' },
                    { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'Designation' },
                    { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'Mobile' }],
        pager: '#dvPagination',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
        sortname: 'RID',
        sortorder: "asc",
        height: 'auto',
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: '',
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: 'RID' }, 
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: false,
    });
});
```

I'm being able to populate data in jqGrid but the paging is causing a problem. In browser developer console I'm getting a undefined error because of which the paging is not loading properly. I tried to search the problem in google but every result section pointed to include missing jqGrid file **`grid.locale-en.js`** which I have already included in my view some suggested to check if **`grid.locale-en.js`** is loaded before **`jquery.jqGrid.js`** so when I tracked down in network I got following result.

[image]

After doing lots of R&D I'm still not been able to resolve following error:-

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'integer' of undefined

**Note:-** Jquery libraries has already been defined in layout head section.

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid you use?** Which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) of jqGrid you use? Your `colModel` contains an important error:  one can't include `key: true` property to more as one item. You can remove all the properties or to hold it for `RID` only. You can try to use URLs to free jqGrid described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) or from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/). Is it work?

Comment: **Verify that `jquery-grid.locale-en.js` really exist. Typical file name is `i18n/grid.locale-en.js`**. In case of usage free jqGrid fork you don't need to include English locale file (`grid.locale-en.js`). In any way I recommend you to use non-minimized version `jquery.jqgrid.js` and start the page in debugger (Developer Tools of IE/Chrome). If you would get the same error then you can see the exact line of `jquery.jqgrid.js` where the error take place. The line number together with the version of jqGrid can help to understand the origin of the error.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Oleg and identifying the mistakes well I have finally sorted it out. While installing jqGrid plugin from nuget all related package were properly installed but I couldn't find  **`jquery-grid.locale-en.js`** in the package but later found that one in sub package where multi-lingual **`jquery-grid.locale-xx.js`** are saved. As I couldn't find the missing plugin I downloaded it from jqGrid official website and included it in my script package. After posting here I made a thorough look in the JS file identified the problem.

Comment: What is "jqGrid official website" now? **Which version and which fork of jqGrid you use now?** I wrote about the changes of licence agreement and the name of jqGrid. Since one year there are no more the product under the name "jqGrid" there are two main forks: free jqGrid (my fork, the last version is 4.11.1) and Guriddo jqGrid JS (last version 5.0.1, but from *old site* http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 you can see Guriddo jqGrid JS 4.8.0 *under Guriddo licence and prices*: see http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334).

Comment: One more remark. You use ASP.NET MVC. Then next version of ASP.NET (version 5) don't support more NuGet for *client-side* (any JavaScript library like jQuery, jqGrid, Angular and so on). NuGet will be used only for *server-side* components (mostly C# components, DLLs). You will have to use npm, bower and Grunt or Gulp if you includes JavaScript components in your code (see [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/index.html) and [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/angular.html)). Guriddo is more oriented on PHP, I use ASP.NET 4 and 5 and MVC 4 or 6 myself.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks :) . Actually, I usually use Kendo for binding grid and all but lately due to certain requirement I need client side plugin some of my colleagues told me about jqGrid so I thought of getting some hands on it. Most forums targeted this website [Trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). So, I assumed this as official site.

Comment: You are welcome! [Trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) was really an official web site for jqGrid *before*. The page now is just a trap. One can just download the new version from the place as before and update it on his old web site. One can get later from lawyer about illegal usage and the requirement on compensation. I'm not sure about the Tony's plans about it, but such scenario is really possible and it would be absolutely legal and profitable.

Comment: @Oleg . http://ui-grid.info/ : 3348 commits, 201 contributors. It looks like jqgrid OData plugin developer has ported its plugin to it, switched to angular and jqGrid OData is no more developed. Will angular grid kill jqgrid ? This may be real killer, not Tony.

Comment: @Andrus: Sorry, but your comment have no relation to the question. The developer of OData plugin posted 2 days ago [the pull request](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/pull/184) to jqGrid, which I will apply in modified form. It means that [Mark Babayev](https://github.com/mirik123) (the developer of OData plugin for free jqGrid) do use jqGrid.

Comment: @Andrus: About integration in Angular: Angular have `directive` feature, which allows to integrate any DOM based or jQuery plugin very easy in Angular project. See the source code of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/angular-popover-ng-click1.htm), which I posted for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29525862/315935), but one can use it. See [the plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qxFr7fwbPkyNMziZEiqN?p=preview), which I posted in [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124174/jqgrid-treegrid-doesnt-work-with-my-angular-directive#comment56058296_34124174).

Answer (score 1):

Please include always the exact version number of jqGrid, which you use, and the information about the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7), which you use.

I suppose that you use some old version of jqGrid and you just used wrong name for locale (localization) file. The file name `jquery-grid.locale-en.js` is very suspected. The distribution of jqGrid have `i18n` with the file `grid.locale-en.js`. The usage of old jqGrid without locale file can produce the error `Cannot read property 'integer' of undefined` during filling the pager of jqGrid.

Another important error in your code is the usage of `key: true` property for more as one column. The column have to have unique values in every row. The property `key: true` informs jqGrid to use the contains from the column instead of the `id` property. You used already the option `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: 'RID' }` which informs to use `RID` property of items as the rowid. This I would recommend you to remove unneeded hidden `RID` column from `colModel` and remove `key: true, hidden: false` from all other columns. You can remove options with default values: `mtype: 'get'`, `sortorder: "asc"`, `caption: ''` and `multiselect: false`.

I would recommend you to try to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), it's the fork of jqGrid, which I develop after Tony Tomov have changed the licence agreement of jqGrid and it's name to [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)). Many new features, which 
I implemented in free jqGrid are described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and readmes to all versions currently published.